# How can i fix the space left in images list

Tags: php, css

Please refer to image i have attached for better understanding, May be my problem can be adjusted through css, Please help

Regards

https://i.stack.imgur.com/710hT.png

Comment: Please include the problem statement and the code which causes the problem *in* your question.

Comment: You need to make an MCVE, not just include a picture.

Comment: easy; your (source) image heights all must be the same. If you're even 1px off, it will do that. Classic bootstrap issue. it's not flowing correctly. (I should have put this as answer really).

Comment: That ^ or make your containers the same height and everything should flow correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the simple issue. This is happening because of the uneven height of your picture with text. Try giving min-height to the div.

**Eg**: `.somediv{ min-height: 200px;}`

**Recommented** If you want to set the height dynamically use simple piece of javascript.

```
 equalheight = function(container) {

        var currentTallest = 0,
            currentRowStart = 0,
            rowDivs = new Array(),
            $el,
            topPosition = 0;
        $(container).each(function() {

            $el = $(this);
            $($el).height('auto')
            topPostion = $el.position().top;

            if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
                for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
                    rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
                }
                rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
                currentRowStart = topPostion;
                currentTallest = $el.height();
                rowDivs.push($el);
            } else {
                rowDivs.push($el);
                currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
            }
            for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
        });
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {   //to work in resize
        equalheight('.somediv');
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
     equalheight('.somediv');
    });
```

**This code will give equal height to all divs and keep the images well aligned**

Comment: yeah I said that 6 mins. prior to your answer.